Difficult set of differential equations for epidemiology help needed (three equations in total)
The equations are mostly simple operations, but I can’t solve it. I tried a bit of substitution, but I think I am doing it wrong.I am doing this out of pure curiosity.This is a set of equations representing the SIR model in epidemiology,and I decided to create a set of differential equations and solve it,though you can tell the second step failed.This is mostly just for fun though.
I am bad at solving differential equations and would like to learn from y’all‘s solutions and methods.So,learning plays a part to.
$I’(t)=Sr_0$
$R(t)=N-I(t)-S(t)$
$S(t)=N-I(t)-R(t)$
$I(0)=I_0$
Please show steps and $S$,$r_0$,&$I_0$ are all constants ($r_0$ is not the starting value for $R(t)$)

It may be only me but I don't see any picture. Do you know how to use $\LaTeX$?

Then learn: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Well a way you could solve that system of differential equations is first to reduce it to a single one. I will use dot notation since it's easier to format in LaTeX. So lets express everything in terms of $R$. Firstly substitute $S=\frac{\dot{I}}{r_{0}}$ into the other equations. The new set of equations you will get is $$\Biggl\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{\ddot{I}}{r_0}=N-I - R \\ \dot{R}=N-I-\frac{\dot{I}}{r_{0}} \end{matrix}$$ Now since $R=N-I-\frac{\ddot{I}}{r_{0}}$ we can substitute to get $-\dot{I}-\frac{\dddot{I}}{r_{0}}=N-I-\frac{\dot{I}}{r_{0}}$ Well let's first solve for $N=0, I=e^{qt}.$ $$qr_{0}+q³=r_{0}+q \\ \implies q³+(r_{0}-1)q-r_{0}=0$$ It is clear that 1 is a root of this polynomial since the coefficient sum is 0. So from polynomial division we can find the other two roots: $$q³-q²+q²-q+r_{0}q-r_{0}=(q-1)(q²+q+r_{0})$$ which gives us the two roots $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4r_{0}}}{2}$. Now blending back to non-homogeneous, we can add a $k$ to save the day.
$I(t)=e^{qt}+k$ so we can substitute back into the equation and get $$-qr_{0}Ce^{qt}-q³Ce^{qt}=Nr_{0}-Cr_{0}e^{qt}-kr_{0}-qCe^{qt}$$ so $k=N,q\in \{1,\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4r_{0}}}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-4r_{0}}}{2}\}$ and I guess getting a restraint on $C$ is gonna be streightforward from substituting back $R$ and $S$. But we do know that $I(0)$ should be $I_{0}$ but in our function it is $C+N$ so $C=I_{0}-N$ and there we have an expression for C by the question parameters. So $$I(t)=(I_{0}-N)e^{qt}+N$$. I'm too tired to solve for the other ones myself, but it should be streightforward since $S$ is only $\dot{I}$ with a factor and $R$ can be easily expressed in terms of the two others from the 1st equation.
